# How can I tell which Bing Maps version I'm using?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, bing-maps

Am I doing something wrong with my Bing Maps referencing?

In References | Add Reference, I add version 1.0

But if I look at Tools | Extensions and Updates | Installed | SDKs, it says it is version 1.1.20120927.1

Why the numbering mismatch? Am I somehow not actually referencing the newest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version number in the SDK is correct. The number showing up in the reference panel is misleading. It is showing the major version number but isn't telling you the minor version. As long as you only have one version of the Bing Maps control installed and do not have the beta still installed then you will be fine as only the version that is installed will be used. If your application was trying to reference an older version of the map control which wasn't installed you would get an error when compiling or see a warning icon on the reference.